# variable access between Function calls behavior in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am doing recursion and storing the value in every step if calling.
Like if my working program-code is like-

```
lst=[]
def after_occurance(ls,l,curr):
    for i in range(l,curr):
        if ls[i]==ls[curr]:
            return False
    return True

def permutate(A,l,r):
    if l==r:
        ans=A.copy()
        print(A,ans)
        # change the commenting of the following 2 lines to see the difference

        lst.append(A)
        #lst.append(ans)

        print(lst)
        return lst
    else:
        for i in range(l,r+1):
            if after_occurance(A,l,i):
                A[i],A[l] = A[l],A[i]
                permutate(A,l+1,r)
                hm[A[l]]=1
                A[l],A[i] = A[i],A[l]
            else:
                continue
lst.clear()
A=[1,2,6]
A=sorted(A)
permutate(A,0,len(A)-1)
return lst
```

> Following are 2 kind of outputs when Toggling between 2 commented line respectively

```
[1, 2, 6] [1, 2, 6]
[[1, 2, 6]]
[1, 6, 2] [1, 6, 2]
[[1, 2, 6], [1, 6, 2]]
[2, 1, 6] [2, 1, 6]
[[1, 2, 6], [1, 6, 2], [2, 1, 6]]
[2, 6, 1] [2, 6, 1]
[[1, 2, 6], [1, 6, 2], [2, 1, 6], [2, 6, 1]]
[6, 2, 1] [6, 2, 1]
[[1, 2, 6], [1, 6, 2], [2, 1, 6], [2, 6, 1], [6, 2, 1]]
[6, 1, 2] [6, 1, 2]
[[1, 2, 6], [1, 6, 2], [2, 1, 6], [2, 6, 1], [6, 2, 1], [6, 1, 2]]
[1 2 6 ] [1 6 2 ] [2 1 6 ] [2 6 1 ] [6 1 2 ] [6 2 1 ]
```

```
[1, 2, 6] [1, 2, 6]
[[1, 2, 6]]
[1, 6, 2] [1, 6, 2]
[[1, 6, 2], [1, 6, 2]]
[2, 1, 6] [2, 1, 6]
[[2, 1, 6], [2, 1, 6], [2, 1, 6]]
[2, 6, 1] [2, 6, 1]
[[2, 6, 1], [2, 6, 1], [2, 6, 1], [2, 6, 1]]
[6, 2, 1] [6, 2, 1]
[[6, 2, 1], [6, 2, 1], [6, 2, 1], [6, 2, 1], [6, 2, 1]]
[6, 1, 2] [6, 1, 2]
[[6, 1, 2], [6, 1, 2], [6, 1, 2], [6, 1, 2], [6, 1, 2], [6, 1, 2]]
[1 2 6 ] [1 2 6 ] [1 2 6 ] [1 2 6 ] [1 2 6 ] [1 2 6 ]
```

Can somebody explain this behavior and what basic rule should I follow while doing Recursive calls and variable access in python?

Comment: Are you asking why you have to copy the list to get the correct result?

Comment: Please clarify your issue. Your code is not recursive, and it is not clear which input gives what output, not what output you expect instead.

Comment: Yes means why is it like that? and what is the approach i should follow when storing values between recursive calls @HymnsForDisco

Comment: @MisterMiyagi its recursive I hide unnecessary recursive code under the #some code section

Comment: Do you want me to include the recursive call code in it for your clarification? which I excluded for preciseness? @MisterMiyagi

Comment: To `.copy()` or not to `.copy()`, it should be a distinct, deliberate choice which substantially changes the logic of your program.  If you do not know which choice is appropriate, perhaps you must do some reading about what `list.copy()` does, and why it is used.  It is a commonly used tool that is well documented.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I read about the lit.copy() and I understand what it is doing.
my point is when I am doing `print(x,x.copy())` it does give same value, tthen why it is different while appendin it in another list- i.e I am not clear about the variable access pattern in between different function/recursive calls

Comment: I'm sorry to say it is not clear what you mean by "variable access pattern".  It is my assessment that the problem you are facing is due to a lack of understanding of `copy` and its purpose.  "**why it is different while appendin it in another list**".  As I stated before, using `copy` vs not using `copy` is a distinct, deliberate choice which substantially changes the logic of your program. If you repeatedly append the same list to a list without using `copy`, you are effectively making a outer list which references the same inner list over and over, hence`[1 2 6 ] [1 2 6 ] [1 2 6 ]...`

Comment: You should show how you call your function and the value of the parameters you supply and the required outputs. Also you should post code that the very helpful people here can just copy and paste and run on their own machines.

Comment: @quamrana sure I have added it

Comment: First don't add links to resources that might disappear in the future, instead paste *text* of code. Second the code at the link bares little resemblance to what you have already posted.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, hope current edit helps to understand @quamrana

Comment: Ok, so now you've completely changed the code which invalidates all the comments from the beginning. Also you still haven't shown `def after_occurance()`, nor your sample inputs nor the call site.

Comment: yes shown @quamrana

Comment: And the sample inputs and the call site?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the code you really wanted to post:

```
def after_occurance(ls, l, curr):
    for i in range(l, curr):
        if ls[i] == ls[curr]:
            return False
    return True

def permutate(A, l, r):
    if l == r:
        ans = A.copy()

        # change the commenting of the following 2 lines to see the difference
        #lst.append(A)
        lst.append(ans)

        return
    else:
        for i in range(l, r + 1):
            if after_occurance(A, l, i):
                A[i],A[l] = A[l],A[i]
                permutate(A, l + 1, r)
                A[l],A[i] = A[i],A[l]
            else:
                continue

lst = []
A = [1,2,6]
A = sorted(A)
permutate(A, 0, len(A) - 1)
print(lst)
```

The difference comes from appending a `copy()` of `A` or just a reference to `A`.

When you append a reference to `A`, all the future changes to `A` show up in `lst` because the result is `lst = [A, A, A, A, A, ....]` and so `lst` cannot be anything apart from a list of the same thing.

When you append a `copy()` of `A`, you make a new `list` which is not changed after the `append()` and so records the history of how `A` looked over time.

Comment: but according to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/ *A shallow copy means constructing a new collection object and then populating it with references to the child objects found in the original.* which means copy() also holds the reference in the original array

Comment: No, exactly the opposite. You have a new collection which has no access to the original container. However, it *does* reference the original contents. A deepcopy would also make copies of all the children, recursively.

Comment: No, the article is correct, your summary was wrong. There is a diagram labelled ‘Shallow Copy’ which has bag1 and bag2. Neither has a reference to each other, but have references to the same contents initially. You can go on to change one bag without affecting the other.